# what is atomic element size, and how to check the atomic element size of PC

Tags: endianness, cpu-registers

While reading the wiki page for the eidianess: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness.
I found that the bit sequence of a 4-Byte LWord in the memory depends on the atomic element size. Am i correct on this?
I suppose the atomic element size is the size of a register. But I cannot find any info on this terminology. 
Also, how to check the atomic element size of PC?

Comment: You fell to a joke which comes from autosar community. They managed to write hundreds of pages of specifications covering all combinations of how you can arrange bits in a byte and bytes to each other and giving them names. From that, they managed to specify the most complex xml format to describe those combinations one could possibly conceive. All that under the wrong assumption that you pinning a 1 bit logic analyzer to a bit stream and what you see there is of any relevance for how software processes the received data.

Comment: @user2225104 this comment does not help much...

Comment: It should. As long as you operate on one computer only there is nothing to worry about. Your (higher level language) code will always work. As long as you have computers communicating with each other using a well defined network byte order and message protocol, you still have nothing to worry about. Only if you try to do what those guys (Tm) think one could do, you will run into such issues.

Comment: @user2225104 Well, that's what i'm doing right now( try to do what those guys think one could do)...

Comment: Time to browse the web for a new job, I guess ;)

Comment: @henryyao I agree that the comment is a bit dense, but I think what user2225104 is trying to say is that 5 computers could interpret the same sequence of bytes 5 different ways in memory, but so long as your program is communicating with another instance of your program (or your server communicating with your client, or whatever) on each computer, how the host system chooses to interpret the bytes is irrelevant, only how your program interprets them.

Answer (score 0):

I think atomic element size is the minimum size that you treat the bits, such as a "short" or an "unsigned int", the atomic element size is 16, or 32 respectively.